# Storing user sockets mapping into global variable

Tags: node.js, socket.io

we are implementing chat and other notifications by socket.io in node js project.

we need to keep user -> socket mapping.

For this we have declare global variable in app.js

```
global.user_sockets = {};
```

and assign userid, socket mapping in user_sockets array when new connection creates after token authetication.

```
user_sockets[data.userId]=socket;
```

For using global variable there are many speculations. some users say it will be not good when using with multiple process.

Any other solutions on this?

Comment: have you look into Redis publish /subscribe?

Comment: we thought about that as well, but does it useful to add another in-memory management layer instead of this implementation?

Comment: well if your users start a session with logging in, you can just associate the socket.id with the users session id then can either work with passing socket.io server object around as an parameter and call emit etc. You can also use the Redis publish/subscribe and just publish formatted messages and let a subscriber function handle everything and keep it minimal with entire work into one script. As many will agree using globals is not the best choice. You might want to evaluate many/other options to conclude which is best for your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `user_sockets` as a parameter to the functions where ever you are using instead of global variable. But this increases the number of parameters by 1 which I think its not a problem.